# <apex:pageBlockSectionItem> doesn't have id after it is rendered into html

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have a freaking strange situation. I set id for `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` tag but when it is rendered into html it doesn't have id. Other tags have but not this type of apex tag.

Why? Is it a normal behaviour for this tag?

The reason I'm asking is that I want to show/hide it using jQuery. This functionality works fine for `<apex:pageBlockSection>` tag, but not for `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is most likely that the `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` is not directly represented in the HTML.

For example, with a two column layout the HTML is (roughly):

```
<tr><th>Label 1</th><td>Value 1</td><th>Label 2</th><td>Value 2</td></tr>
```

and if an element was emitted around the label/value pair it would break the table structure.

So you will have to add ids or classes to both the label and value components and adjust your jQuery accordingly.

Comment: I understand that. So why there is an id attribute in <apex:pageBlockSectionItem> tag?

Comment: @Chiz I guess this uncommon case of the id not being useful hasn't been added to the Visualforce compiler or the documentation. You can post a comment to the documentation people using the "Was this information helpful?" box.

Comment: css was the answer to my problem :-\

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery on the `id` parameter, you have to take into account how Salesforce encodes the `id`.  First, try going to a VF Page, right click over a part of it and click  <kbd>Inspect Element</kbd> , and see what the actual `id` is for that html-element.  You'll see it's encoded.  Here's docs on how to use `Component Ids`:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm

To avoid all that, just add a `styleClass` (if you can) to access the data via jQuery.  Some `<apex:`-tags don't have a `styleClass` parameter, so simply wrap that class in an `<apex:outputPanel styleClass="gotchaCovered">`.

```
<script>
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    function toggleGotchaCovered(){
        j$('.gotchaCovered').toggle();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This gets my vote. I know CSS purists would balk at the use of a class as an effective ID, but it sure does make life easier ;)